# unable to share data between components in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular2-directives

Hi I am developing angular2 application. I am trying to share data between components. This is my app.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child;
 message: string;
 ngAfterViewInit() {
 alert(this.message = this.child.message);}
```

this is my login.component.ts

```
message: string = "Hola Mundo!";
```

Whenever my app loaded i am getting below error.

```
RROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'message' of undefined
    at AppComponent.ngAfterViewInit (app.component.ts:88)
```

Can someone help me to fix this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You should refer this link https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: i refered same link and implemented. Tried Child to Parent: Sharing Data via ViewChild() does not work

Comment: From `error`, you got `this.child` variable `undefined`. please post complete code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share between parent component and child component what I do is to pass via parameter in the html. Like this:

```
<app-child [parameterName]="value"></app-child>
```

What I also do, is to have a service who saves the relevant data that all my views are going to consume, and consume the service instead of the past view.

---

Having said that, what you can also do is to have a Router set up, and pass the parameter by get

```
this.router.navigate(['home/:id']);
```

and then in the other component you should get it like so

```
this.route.paramMap
.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
  console.log(params.get('id')); //prints the id
```

I leave you this for that regard, is very useful, i got my answer for you almost exclusively from there

https://angular.io/guide/router

> (Note: there are a million ways to "pass a parameter" but it all
>   depends in how you want it to be done. Maybe it's a public parameter,
>   and you want the user to be able to see it, maybe it's the hash of a
>   password and you want to remain under the hood, for further
>   information, edit your post, and explain a little better, precisely
>   what you want)

Comment: Thank you. I tried in many ways but none of them worked for me.  i thought of asking through this blog.

Comment: If it works for you don´t forget to mark as solution!